# What material is Iron Man's armor made of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

As I recall, a tank knocked Iron Man in the first MCU movie, but he survived (with some black spots on the armor).

AFAIK, Vibranium is in limited supply in the MCU (Captain America's shield). Tony created Vibranium (Tony might call it Badassium) in *Iron Man 2*, and that's also in limited supply.

So what material is Iron Man's armor made of? It doesn't look like iron to me.

Comment: I think Tony said himself in the first film that it was a "Gold-titanium alloy". I can't remember for sure.

Comment: Allegedly, the new element that Tony created in Iron Man 2 is informally called [Badassium](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Tony_Stark's_New_Element).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - that certainly sounds like something Stark would name it!

Comment: Actually, Tony didn't discover a new element, he rediscovered vibranium and was able to synthesize it.  Something his father was never able to do due to the limits of technology.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure that was Vibranium. @PaulD.Waite

Comment: @Robert: gotcha, thank you.

Comment: @SS: [the novelisation apparently agrees](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Vibranium).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Gold Titanium alloy

#### Less short answer:

After his first few attempts at creating a good suit: the first being the ugly thing from the cave and the second being the chromy suit he uses for his first flight, he decides to use a Gold Titanium Alloy that was used on the Seraphim satellite.

> **Tony Stark:** Connect to the sys. co. Have it reconfigure the shell metals. Use the gold titanium alloy from the seraphim tactical satellite. That should ensure a fuselage integrity while maintaining power-to-weight ratio. Got it?

-Tony Stark, Iron Man (2008). Source: [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/quotes)

Comment: Gold Titanium alloy can withstand Tank shell?

Comment: Within the Marvel Cinematic Universe, I would say a definite Yes. In the real world, I am afraid I am not qualified to provide a reliable answer. The Wiki article on Titanium does state that it is used for Armor Plating, but to what extent that armor can protect you is uncllear.

Comment: perfect answer from movie canon reference.. wonder what he used to make the hulkbuster though.. sure will need something much stronger for a bout with Hulk..

Comment: I work in manufacturing and I had always mistakenly assumed it was a Titanium Nitride coating that gave the armor its golden color.   http://www.maford.com/Img/series/112.gif